# Minecraft NEI it is stuck in recipe mode I tried everything. How to get it to cheat mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

[image]

I'm just playing FTB Infinity and my cheat mode For NEI dose not work. I could really use some help. If anyone would know how to fix it I need the answer. I have image of my config if that helps

Answer (score 1):

World settings override global settings, go into the NEI options menu, click inventory, then toggle the global button on the top left hand corner to world. Then change it to cheat mode.

Answer (score 0):

Launch FTB Infinity, go into single player/multi player then press E. There will be a button in the bottom left hand corner of the screen that says "Options", click that. Then click inventory, then click the recipe mode button until it says cheat mode.